# SEO lite - remove company name

Tags: add-on

[image]

Hello,
Hope somebody can help? I only have very little experience with EE. I want to remove the company name - marked with yellow (see picture). Can anybody tell me how to - and where to do it. I am using Seo Lite?? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how it was set up by the developer, but possibly all you will need to do is update the SEO Lite Template.

Go to *Add-ons > Modules > Seo Lite* and check what's in the template field. I'm guessing the `{site_name}` variable is what you'll want to remove (or possibly the actual text "zumoQR - DK"), but hard to know without seeing your setup.

Documentation: http://wedoaddons.com/seo-lite/configuration

Edit your original question to add more detail if you are still stuck after checking your SEO Lite settings.